# Must the C++ standard library support classes that are picky about who their friends are?

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer, friend, access-modifiers

This question is easiest to illustrate with an example, so here goes:

#### Is code like the following guaranteed to be valid, and compile & run correctly?

(Not all implementations actually compile it correctly, but I'm wondering if that's a bug.)

```
#include <algorithm>
class Picky
{
    friend
        Picky *std::copy<Picky const *, Picky *>(Picky const *, Picky const *, Picky *);
    Picky &operator =(Picky const &) { return *this; }
public:
    Picky() { }
};

int main()
{
    Picky const a;
    Picky b;
    std::copy<Picky const *, Picky *>(&a, &a + 1, &b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What stdlib implementation does this actually compile on? I wouldn't have thought a single one that didn't delegate `std::copy` to some internal helper existed.

Comment: @Praetorian: I haven't found any, but I could certainly write one myself that works...

Comment: If it does require this to work, it's a defect in the standard.

Comment: @T.C.: Why would it be? (Why) must every facility accessible to the standard library be publicly available to all callers?

Comment: Sure, but you'd either be in SFINAE hell, or you'd have to forgo `memcpy` optimizations and such for trivially copyable types. Anyway, the answer to your question is certainly - no, no such guarantee exists. This is kinda the same as befriending `std::default_delete` and trying to stick a type with a private destructor in a `unique_ptr`, that's not guaranteed to work either.

Comment: @Praetorian Or befriending `make_shared` and try to make it use a private constructor.

Comment: @Praetorian: I'm inclined to believe you but I'm not sure where the standard mandates that e.g. a copy-assignment operator must be publicly visible. Do you happen to have a reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::copy` requires an output iterator ([algorithms.general]/p5); output iterators, among other things, require `*r = o` to be valid ([output.iterators], Table 108) - not just "valid sometimes" or "valid in some contexts".

Since for `Picky *p, a;`, `*p = a` isn't valid in most contexts, `Picky *` isn't a valid output iterator.

---

> Hmm it'd be great if you could generalize your answer to other things
>   beyond the particular example I gave. Like, for example,
>   `std::vector::push_back(T const &)`, or whatever.

Befriending a member function is an absolute no-no, because you aren't even guaranteed that there's a member function with that signature ([member.functions]/p2, which Stephan T. Lavavej calls the ["STL Implementers Can Be Sneaky Rule"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4245.html#2435)):

> An implementation may declare additional non-virtual member function
>   signatures within a class:
>
> - by adding arguments with default values to a member function signature<sup>187</sup> [*Note*: An implementation
>     may not add arguments with default values to virtual, global, or non-member functions. — *end note*];
> - by replacing a member function signature with default values by two or more member function signatures with equivalent behavior; and
> - by adding a member function signature for a member function name.
>
> <sub><sup>187</sup> Hence, the address of a member function of a class in the C++ standard library has an unspecified type.</sub>

Comment: Hmm it'd be great if you could generalize your answer to other things beyond the particular example I gave. Like, for example, `std::vector<T>::push_back(T const &)`, or whatever.

Comment: Interesting edit. That has nontrivial implications -- are you saying I'm not even allowed to say `void (std::vector<int>::*push_back)(int const &) = &std::vector<int>::push_back;`? In other words, I can't take the addresses of member functions at all based on their signature in the standard, because they might not exist?

Comment: @Mehrdad No, you can't. The standard actually calls this out in a footnote, which I added to the quote.

Comment: Hmm, what about `std::swap` in C++11? Can you make `T::T(T &&)` and `T &T::operator =(T &&)` private and declare `std::swap<T>` as a friend and expect it to work? That's neither a member function nor does it require iterators.

Comment: @Mehrdad No; it requires `MoveConstructible` and `MoveAssignable`, and both requires the relevant constructs to be unconditionally valid.

Answer (score 1):

The code might compile if `std::copy()` does not call any other non-friend functions but I've yet to encounter any such implementation.     And there is no requirement in the standard limiting HOW `std::copy()` achieves the required effect.

However, it does require a working and accessible assignment operator.